# How I can use perl + burp?

Tags: burp-suite, perl

How can I use [any]-perl script for pentesting (for example: script for subdomains enumeration)?

How to redirect output from a perl-script to burp? This is possible? How can this architecture be implemented? Thanks!

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent("$0/0.1 " . $ua->agent);
$ua->agent("Mozilla/5.0");

open my $fh, '<', 'wordlist.txt' or die $!;

while ( <$fh> ) {
next unless /\S/;
chomp;

my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => "http://$_.foobar.baz");
my $res = $ua->request($req);

print $res->content;
}
```

In this example, I send requests to `http://[wordlist].foobar.baz` and receive responses to the terminal, ok, good. It's faster. But, in theory, can every response be sent to Burp?

[image]

Comment: I have no idea what you are really asking. Especially what you mean with "redirecting output... to burp" - because it is unclear what burp should do with some arbitrary output of a script. If you instead want to know how to use burp to intercept HTTP requests made by a perl script: this depends on the exact script and libraries used, i.e. no way that works in all cases. But it is common to honor environment variables like `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` to specify the proxy (i.e. in this case Burp) to use.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I update Q, please see.

Comment: Still unclear. Burp is not something you just send a response too but Burp is a proxy and thus on the path between client and server, i.e. sees and can modify request and similar with the response. If you want to do this just set the proxy as hinted in my previous comment and documented for LWP::UserAgent (i.e. use `env_proxy` or `proxy` method). If you just want do somehow send the response to Burp please explain what you expect Burp to do with this response.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich in prev. example (pl code) I enumerate subdomains, right?! So, if I'll being this operation in Intruder, its take a lot of  time (if my wordlist > 1000000 words) This never end. If I running .pl script and send output to burp, process end will quick. No?

Comment: As already said, just use `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`. Turn Interception Off and run your perl script, you'll have all the request logged in sitemap as well has proxy history.